# How do I find the Serial Number of a USB Drive?

Tags: usb

I'm trying to re-enable USB Autoplay in a secure way, by installing a program on each of the computers that I use so that I can run my launcher ([PStart](http://www.pegtop.net/start/) in this case) whenever I plug in my specific USB drive.  The tool that I'm using to enable this - [AutoRunGuard](http://autorun.synthasite.com/AutoRunGuard.php) - needs the serial number of the USB drive that I am using.  I can't figure out where to find this in Windows.  Ideally I would not need to install and run a separate program to do this (seemingly) simple task.

Since this is a pretty easy question, bonus points if you also tell me how to discover it in Linux as well.

**What steps do I need to take to retrieve a USB Drive's serial number?**

**UPDATE:**
Just incase people come here looking for the answer for AutoRunGuard, I discovered that they don't want the USB device serial number, but the *volume* serial number.  The drive serial can be found by going into the command line, navigating to the drive, and executing `dir`.  The volume serial number is found in the top two lines - use it without the dash.

Comment: Just for completeness-- if you're looking for how to do this on MacOS and you arrived here, check out https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/275382/get-serial-numbers-of-connected-usb-devices

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use the freeware [USBDeview](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/usb_devices_view.html):

> USBDeview is a small utility that
>   lists all USB devices that currently
>   connected to your computer, as well as
>   all USB devices that you previously
>   used. For each USB device, exteneded
>   information is displayed: Device
>   name/description, device type, serial
>   number (for mass storage devices), the
>   date/time that device was added,
>   VendorID, ProductID, and more...
>   USBDeview also allows you to uninstall
>   USB devices that you previously used,
>   and disconnect USB devices that are
>   currently connected to your computer.
>   You can also use USBDeview on a remote
>   computer, as long as you login to that
>   computer with admin user.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

On Linux, [usbview](http://linuxappfinder.com/package/usbview) will do this, just click on the device in the left pane.

Comment: But he was asking about windows...

Comment: **1.** He wants to *use* the information on a MSWindows box, but getting the info on Linux machine probably doesn't require installing anything.  **2.** If you read the post, he said: *bonus points if you also tell me how to discover it in Linux as well.*

Comment: You're right, I apologize.

Answer (score 5):

### Get USB Serial Numbers on Windows with PowerShell

Here's a PowerShell solution that will give you the serial number of all "*USB Mass Storage Devices*" mounted on the system which you run it. It uses [Get-CIMInstance](https://ss64.com/ps/get-ciminstance.html) to query the [Win32_PnPSignedDriver class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/whqlprov/win32-pnpsigneddriver) to get the property values with filtering, looping, setting a couple variables, using a method, etc.

Within the PowerShell script below, I left some commented out logic and comments for running with the legacy [Get-WMIObject](https://ss64.com/ps/get-wmiobject.html) cmdlet for systems with versions below PowerShell 3.0.

### PowerShell

```
$DevId = (((Get-CimInstance -Class win32_PnPSignedDriver) | ?{($_.Description -like '*mass*')}).DeviceID);
$DevSerial = @($DevId | %{$_.Split('\')[2]});
$DevSerial

##### // Everything below is commented out with comments for each section \\ #####

## -- See everything or the selected properties per above
#((Get-CimInstance -Class win32_PnPSignedDriver) | ?{($_.Description -like '*mass*')}) | 
#Select Description, DeviceClass, DeviceID, Manufacturer

## -- Correlated legacy PS code older than PowerShell version 3
#$DevId = ((Get-WmiObject Win32_USBControllerDevice | %{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | ?{($_.Description -like '*mass*')}).DeviceID);
#$DevSerial = @($DevId | %{$_.Split('\')[2]});
#$DevSerial

## -- See everything or selected properties per above legacy PS code
#Get-WmiObject Win32_USBControllerDevice | %{[wmi]($_.Dependent)} | ?{($_.Description -like '*mass*')} | 
#Select Description, DeviceID, Manufacturer, Service
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [Get-CIMInstance](https://ss64.com/ps/get-ciminstance.html)
- [Win32_PnPSignedDriver class](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/whqlprov/win32-pnpsigneddriver)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach
- [Where-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/where-object.html)

  > The '`?`' symbol and Where are both aliases for Where-Object. If you
  >   explicitly want to run the Where-Object command, run Where-object or
  >   '`?`'
- [Comparison Operators](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-compare.html)
- [Split()](https://ss64.com/ps/split.html)
- [PowerShell one liner to get USB Flash Drive Serial Number](http://grandstreamdreams.blogspot.com/2016/02/powershell-one-liner-to-get-usb-flash.html)
- [Get Information from Windows device manager](https://superuser.com/questions/1400457/get-information-from-windows-device-manager)

Answer (score 3):

Under Windows 7.1 Right Click 'Computer' -> 'Manage' -> 'Device Manager' -> Navigate to your USB Drive, Right Click -> Properties -> Details, Property->**Parent**

Value:

```
USB\VID_1058&PID_0830\575833314133343231313937
```

The USB unique id is all the characters after the last \, in this case **575833314133343231313937**

You can also be able to extract it from Property->**Device Instance Path**, however that includes some other fields after the USB unique id part, so is slightly harder to read off.

Answer (score 2):

Open Windows Powershell with Administrative privilege

Type `get-disk`

then it will list you all of the disks on the computer, with disk number on the left.

Suppose the disk in question is number 4.

Type `$a = get-Disk -Number 4`, after which `$a` will be a list contains all the properties of this disk. You can view all those information with `$a | format-list -Property *` Or you can just type `$a.SerialNumber` If you disk has a serial number, The command would return it.

Answer (score -1):

Right Click 'Computer' -> 'Manage' -> 'Device Manager' -> Navigate to your USB Drive, Right Click -> Properties -> Details

**Edit:** Unfortunately I have no idea where he got this IDs from, bu the 'Device Instance Id' is the closest guess I have:

```
USBSTOR\DISK&VEN_&PROD_USB_DISK_2.0&REV_PMAP\07960501655B0CEE&0
```

It should be the last part after the \ and without the &0

Comment: There isn't a dropdown for "serial number".  Is it part of the "Device Instance Id"?  Which part?

Comment: @jamuraa, I've added my guess to my answer.

Comment: I have neither a "Device instance id" nor a "Serial number"

Answer (score -1):

On linux you can simply do,

```
lsusb -v
```

It will print all information about usb devices along with serial number also.